# I need help combining image and audio clips into 1 video

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

My goal is to make a video of a text to speech Reading images i made.

I have the images and audio as files, my goal is to combine them as a slideshow fashion where the image durations last as long as the text to speech audio duration. Also would be nice to have a transition mp4 between the clips.

The problem is that I have no idea where to start. The pymovie documentations don't seem to cover this from my understanding.
**I need directions on where to go/what to use/how to use.**

I am also creating the images in a for loop and planning to make a function to add the image and audio into the file

I have searched for 10-20 minutes now and didn't find anything to help me.
Keep in mind i am a newbie python programmer.

Comment: Maybe it is worthy taking a look into this http://dmgig.com/2016/03/16/ffmpeg-image-slideshow-with-music-and-title-overlay/

Comment: it seems to have a fixed duration